# How would you change file/directory ownership on a Postgres container deployed to kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

The error output when including the below command in the statefulset manifests to change the directory ownership.

“/bin/chown 26:26 -R”

The file belonging to the database system will be owned by user “postgres”

The user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale “en_US.utf8”.

The default database encoding has accordingly been set to “UTF8”.

The default text search configuration will be set to “english”.

Data page checksum are disabled.
initdb: error: directory “/var/lib/postgresql/data” exists but is not empty.

If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty the directory “/var/lib/postgresql/data” or run initdb with an argument other than “/var/lib/postgresql/data”.

Comment: You want to change the permissions or pass trough this error?

Comment: I would like to change ownership permissions to "/var/lib/postgres/data" mounted to an efs volume

Comment: Try to modify the entrypoint before container starts, in this entrypoint run the chmod command.

Comment: You are recommending to modify the entrypoint in the Dockerfile used to build the image?

Comment: No, you can use `--entrypoint` on `docker run`. Execute wherever you want and call the original script.